# Transparent navigation bar in Ionic

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

My Ionic application have a detail view with transparent header. Applying CSS class "bar-clear" to my  element is doing the job just fine in desktop browsers and when running the app on Android (see result [here](http://postimg.org/image/ap1mtp7it/)).

But when running on iOS 8 the header is white and opaque (see [here](http://postimg.org/image/nf5v6sfh1/)).
Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and people it got it working by setting bar-light to the header bar and then making these changes:

```
    .bar.bar-light {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.66) !important; /* or transparent, or background:none */
}
.scroll-content {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

See this playground: http://play.ionic.io/app/3cbf53eff565

Will it work once built? not sure but give it a go and let me know.

Comment: Yes! I could test it on iOS simulator and it works. overflow:visible on scroll-content is the key.

Comment: I've added ```<ion-content class="padding" style="background:blue">``` and the bar isn't transparent...