# Ionic transparent header but keeping navigation button

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on an ionic app, and I'm struggle with this problem for too loog... I would like to remove the header bar (or makes it transparent) but I would like to keep the navigation button. To sum up, I would like to use the slide menu navigation without having the header bar in background.

After researches, I know that

> ion-nav-buttons must be immediate descendants of the ion-view or ion-nav-bar element (basically, don’t wrap it in another div).

So I'm stuck here. To illustrate my needs, here is the top of my app :

[image: On left is what is current, on right is what I want to do]

Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot

NB : doesn't work for me [Transparent navigation bar in Ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092610/transparent-navigation-bar-in-ionic)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic hide nav-bar not the buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37005207/ionic-hide-nav-bar-not-the-buttons)

Comment: I faced the same issue. This would solve your problem too

Answer (score 0):

This should work in your case:

```
.has-header {
    top: 0px;
}
.bar.bar-stable {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
}
```